# Updating weather info, should I use alarm and/or a service?

Tags: android

I am having some design techniques about How shall I schedule a code to retrieve the weather info?
Should I use alarms to retrieve the weather each 10 minutes?
And do I need to run a service for this? Or just put the code in the Broadcastreceiver and start when the alarm fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. Yes, you will need to put this code in either a service or broadcastreceiver because when and activity loses focus (meaning the user is using a different app or the phone is asleep) they pause and/or close. However, i have no experience with either Services or Broadcastrecievers, so that is as much as i can tell you.